# How to get Webpage’s source code in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and C++ language that runs on the console.

I am trying to go to a web page, then get the source of that webpage (What I mean by source is: in Firefox, when you right click, then “View Page Source”) and save it in my computer as a text file, so that I can read that saved file later on.   Can you please give me an example of how to go to a website in c++ and then save the HTML source code in to my computer? I would greatly appreciate any help

And how can you install libcurl?

When I use  `#include <curl/curl.h>` it says Error: cannot open source file “curl/curl.h.”

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no, but it _will be_ depressed when it crawls this question :)

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for the infor. When I use  #include <curl/curl.h> it says Error: cannot open source file “curl/curl.h.” do I have to install this library function? If so, how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: If you're already using Visual Studio, it might be easier to use WinINet. in order to use functions from this API you just need to include `wininet.h` in your source code and add `wininet.lib` to Additional Dependencies in the Linker section of your project settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some of tools that support HTTP e.g. [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Windows) or [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (multiplatform). I was using WinINet for communication with web servers and getting the content of the page was pretty easy. Here are some links to give you a hint of what to do:

[Get web page using WinInet class wrapper](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/generalinternet/article.php/c3411)
[Using WinInet as an alternative to libcurl](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/using-wininet-as-an-alternative-to-libcurl/)

Answer (score 0):

A low level approach: winsockets + HTTP protocol.

Higher level approach: libraries curl, WinINet API and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to know the fundamentals about [protocol layering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_protocol_design_principles#Protocol_layering) and [software layering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_protocol_design_principles#Software_layering) first!

After that, decide on the layer on which you want to develop. Then decide on a low- or high-level API for your specific task.

BTW: Your specific task is not a typical task for C++, you may easily use the `curl` utility, e.g.: `curl YOURURL > file.html`. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

This is a small program , i made to extract & save/write Facebook account source code in a text file. You can change it with your need ( you can change "http://www.facebook.com" with "http://www.google.com/").. Also remember to link wininet.a (library) to your project. Hope it will help :)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream.h>
fstream fs_obj;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  fs_obj.open("temp.txt",ios::out | ios::app);  
  HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenA("InetURL/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0 );

  HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA( hInternet, "www.facebook.com", 80, " "," ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0 ); //enter url here

  HINTERNET hData = HttpOpenRequestA( hConnection, "GET", "/", NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0 );

  char buf[ 2048 ] ;

  HttpSendRequestA( hData, NULL, 0, NULL, 0 ) ;
  string total;
  DWORD bytesRead = 0 ;
  DWORD totalBytesRead = 0 ;

  while( InternetReadFile( hData, buf, 2000, &bytesRead ) && bytesRead != 0 )
  {
    buf[ bytesRead ] = 0 ; // insert the null terminator.
    total=total+buf;
    printf( "%d bytes read\n", bytesRead ) ;

    totalBytesRead += bytesRead ;
  }

  fs_obj<<total<<"\n--------------------end---------------------\n";
  fs_obj.close();
  printf( "\n\n END -- %d bytes read\n", bytesRead ) ;
  printf( "\n\n END -- %d TOTAL bytes read\n", totalBytesRead ) ;

  cout<<endl<<total<<endl; //it will save source code to (temp.txt) file
  InternetCloseHandle( hData ) ;
  InternetCloseHandle( hConnection ) ;
  InternetCloseHandle( hInternet ) ;
  system("pause");
}
```

Rename temp.txt with temp.html , open it with browser you will get that webpage.